# Feedback resistors not connected to boost regulator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I was using a [TPS65131](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65131-q1.pdf) boost regulator and accidentally forgot to add feedback resistor R3. I noticed that my output negative voltage was -30 volts. I realised that there was no feedback and added the resistor R3. Now, I am not getting any negative output voltage at all. Is there any chance that if feedback resistor is not added, the IC can get damaged? The components are added as per the datasheet for +-15 volts.

Comment: Andy's answer indicates it's possible. Also if you have other devices on the board connected to the nominal +/-15V something may have been damaged by the 45V total supply you subjected it/them to.

Comment: That wouldn't have happened since I had isolated the +-15 from the rest of the circuit. i.e I was only testing the boost stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any chance that if feedback resistor is not added, the IC can
>   get damaged?

Yes, it's quite possibly damaged: -

[image]

The absolute limit of voltage difference between the incoming supply and OUTN is 24 volts so, if your incoming supply was 5 volts and you saw -30 volts at the neg output (possibly -30.5 volts at OUTN), that's a total difference of 35 volts and significantly greater than the allowed 24 volts.

Comment: Thanks @Andy aka... But I'd like to know if could missing only that resistor have been the reason for producing such a high voltage?

Comment: Why would you need another reason? Sure, missing thar resistor will max the output and cause damage.

Comment: Okay.....Thanks